# Listen for screen power on / power off even after onDestroy()

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to listen for screen power on / power off in my app but after onDestroy() since the app is destroyed its stops listening is there any way for my app to continue listening after it shuts down like a background process?

BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
                if (i.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                        System.out.println("Screen turned off");
                } else if(i.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                        System.out.println("Screen turned on");
                }
        }
}
```

i put this code in my onCreate() in my main activity

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you register your `ScreenReceiver` in your `AndroidManifest`, you'll get the broadcast even if your app has been destroyed. The only time you won't get the broadcast is if the user force stops the app through settings

something like

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="action_looking_for"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```